# function to return string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call an ajax request to my server for json data using a function. If I console out the `resp` variable inside the ajax function it will show the data successfully. If i try to set the ajax function to a variable, and then console that variable it returns undefined. Any ideas who to make the function request the data and then set ti to a variable to be consoled?

```
function jsonData(URL) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    return resp;
  }
}
xhr.send();
}

jsonString = jsonData(http://mywebsite.com/test.php?data=test);

console.log(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple.. Change your call to by synchronous..

```
xhr.open("GET", URL, false);
```

That being said this will block the browser until the operation has been completed and if you can use a callback instead it would likely be preferred.

```
function jsonData(URL, cb) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      cb(resp);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

jsonData("http://mywebsite.com/test.php?data=test"
        , function(data) { console.log(data); });
```